# Как увеличить межбуквенный интервал в Python -> Tkinter -> Label

Tags: python, шрифты, tkinter, label

В Label Tkinter нужно регулировать межбуквенный интервал, как это реализовать?

Comment: что вы имеете в виду под `выставление шрифта помогает?` ? Куда шрифт надо выставлять? На улицу? Есть шрифт в формате otf, есть объект label в котором надо вывести текст этим шрифтом, не устраивает межбуквенный интервал, хочу его увеличить, как в ворде. Какие есть варианты?

Comment: никак. http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/tkinter.pdf